# Speeding up the sound processing algorithm

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, pyaudio

I use the following code to do some immediate sound processing/analyzing. It works, but really slow (compared to the planned speed). I have added some time markers to find out where the problem is and according to them there shouldn't be any. Typical duration (see below) is <0.01 s for all three computed times but it still takes around a second to complete the loop. Where is the problem?

**Edit:** Please note, that the time measurement is not the real issue here. To prove that: `MyPeaks` basically just finds the maximum of pretty short FFT - nothing expensive. And the problem persists even when these routines are commented out.

- Should I use something different than lambda function to make the cycle?
- Did I make some mistake when starting and recording the stream?
- etc.

  ```
  import pyaudio
  import struct
  import mute_alsa
  import time
  import numpy as np
  from Tkinter import *


  def snd_process(k=0):
   if k<1000:
    t0=time.clock()

    data = stream.read(CHUNK)

    t1=time.clock()

    fl=CHUNK
    int_data = struct.unpack("%sh" %str(fl),data)
    ft=np.fft.fft(int_data)
    ft=np.fft.fftshift(ft)
    ft=np.abs(ft)     

    t2=time.clock()

    pks=MyPeaks(np.log(ft))

    freq_out.configure(text=str(pks))

    t3=time.clock()

    print t1-t0, t2-t1, t3-t2     

    master.after(1, lambda: snd_process(k+1))

  CHUNK = 8000
  FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
  CHANNELS = 1
  RATE = 4000

  p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

  stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
              channels=CHANNELS,
              rate=RATE,
              input=True,
              frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

  #Tkinter stuff
  master=Tk()
  button_play=Button(master, command=snd_process, bg="yellow", text="Analyze")
  button_play.grid(row=0, column=0)
  freq_out = Label(master)
  freq_out.grid(row=0, column=1)
  freq_out.configure(text='base')
  mainloop()
  ```

Comment: Speed up your python by using C! (or cython)

Comment: how do you know the time is processing time not the master.after()? When I've tried numpy against raw C it seems to be quite a bit faster. (for dot which isn't surprising)

Comment: @paddyg I don't, but that's not the issue (see the edit).

Comment: if you run a function every millisecond, and you do that 1000 times, the entire processing _must_ take at least a second, plus the time required to do the actual work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are scheduling 1000 callback in tk main thread; for every callback you are using 1 ms delay (`after()`'s first argument). That means the last loop will start around after 1000 ms (1 second) the first one.

Maybe that is way the loop *still takes around a second to complete*.

So, try to use `after_idle()`. I don't think you really need to *Speeding up the sound processing algorithm* because `np` is already quite efficient.

**[EDIT]**
Surprise!! you are reading from audio channel at every iteration 1 second 8000 bytes in 16 bits format for a 4000 frame rate. You need a second to have it.

Comment: Thanks, but - sadly - it does not work. `after_idle` takes about the same time and when 0 ms timeout is used, it does not update the fields in Tkinter (`freq_out.configure(text=str(pks))`)

Comment: So maybe is better do it in packages of 20 or 50 I don't think you need 1 ms UI refresh granularity...

Comment: @VictorPira Just a note: if your complete cycle without UI take (for instance) 200 ms you are asking a UI refresh of 5000 frame per second: maybe TclTk is not designed for this kind of tasks.

Comment: 200 ms is 5 frames/second. That should be doable. But you are right that forcing a redraw after 1 ms is probably too much.

Comment: @RolandSmith In 200 ms he send 1000 updates -> 1 frame in 0.2 ms -> 5000 frame per second.

Comment: Ever call to `snd_process` (which contains a single `configure` call) is at least 1 ms apart. So the complete cycle *cannot* finish in 200 ms.

Comment: Oh, that was really stupid... But believe me guys that I have tried all of the suggestions.

Comment: using zero with `after` isn't a very good idea, as it will possibly starve the event queue, preventing tkinter from handling other events.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thank I'm not a Tk expert ... I don't use it at all :)

Answer (score 2):

Squeezing I/O and calculations into the main loop like you are doing is the classical solution. But there are alternatives.

1. Do the audio gathering and  calculations in a second thread. Since both I/O and numpy should release the GIL, it might be a good alternative here. There is a caveat here. Since GUI toolkits like TKinter are generally not multithread-safe, you should *not* make Tkinter calls from the second thread. But you could set up a function that is called with `after` to check the progress of the calculation and update the UI say every 100 ms.
2. Do the audio gathering and calculations in a different `multiprocessing.Process`. This makes it completely separate from your GUI. You will have to set up a communication channel like e.g. a `Queue` to send the `pks` back to the main process. You should use an `after` function to check if the `Queue` has data available and to update the display if so.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the OS you're running at you might nog be measuring actual 'wall-clock' time. See here http://pythoncentral.io/measure-time-in-python-time-time-vs-time-clock/ for some details. Note that for python 3.3 time.clock is deprecated and time.process_time() or time.perf_counter() is recommended.